# Hardfault handling - Arm Cortex-M0

Tags: c, assembly, arm, cortex-m

I'm having some difficulty creating a hard fault handler for the NRF51 which has an ARM CortexM0.

(note: the following code has been combined from different sources on the internet)
Here's what I have so far:

```
    static void hard_fault_handler_c(unsigned int * hardfault_args)
{
    unsigned int stacked_r0;
    unsigned int stacked_r1;
    unsigned int stacked_r2;
    unsigned int stacked_r3;
    unsigned int stacked_r12;
    unsigned int stacked_lr;
    unsigned int stacked_pc;
    unsigned int stacked_psr;

    stacked_r0 = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[0]);
    stacked_r1 = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[1]);
    stacked_r2 = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[2]);
    stacked_r3 = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[3]);

    stacked_r12 = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[4]);
    stacked_lr = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[5]);
    stacked_pc = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[6]);
    stacked_psr = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[7]);

    for(;;);
}

void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    asm volatile(  
        "movs r0, #4\t\n"  
        "mov  r1, lr\t\n"  
        "tst  r0, r1\t\n" /* Check EXC_RETURN[2] */  
        "beq 1f\t\n"  
        "mrs r0, psp\t\n"  
        "ldr r1,=hard_fault_handler_c\t\n"  
        "bx r1\t\n"  
        "1:mrs r0,msp\t\n"  
        "ldr r1,=hard_fault_handler_c\t\n"  
        : /* no output */  
        : /* no input */  
        : "r0" /* clobber */  
    );  
}
```

The error during compilation is the following:
Building target: project.elf
Invoking: Cross ARM C++ Linker
C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Temp\ccuAgDyP.ltrans9.ltrans.o: In function `HardFault_Handler':
<artificial>:(.text.HardFault_Handler+0x18): undefined reference to`hard_fault_handler_c'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [FruityMesh.elf] Error 1
makefile:65: recipe for target 'project.elf' failed

In summary, it looks like the linker is having trouble finding the address for hard_fault_handler_c function. I would think that i would need to write assembly to import or include the path to this function but, this is just my suggestion. I haven't been able to write assembly for the M0 that compiles to do so.

Thank you

Comment: Why is it declared as `static`? What if you remove it? Perhaps the inline assembly is interpreted as a different translation unit..

Comment: Why would the compiler export a symbol for a static function that is, as far as it can tell, entirely unused? It may have even optimised it away completely. Flow control like that inside inline asm is not something you should a) expect to work, and b) ever do. There's no good reason not to write that control logic in C anway; you have at most 3 instructions that might need asm statements to grab the appropriate special register into a C variable (if you don't have suitable intrinsics).

Comment: Look at your map file and see what symbols are generated.  Almost certainly 'static' is causing that function to not have a global symbol (or a mangled global symbol)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest upgrading to [version 11](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF5_SDK/nRF5_SDK_v11.x.x/) of the NRF SDK, which adds built-in support for a hard fault handler (see nRF5_SDK_11.0.0_89a8197/components/libraries/hardfault).